# How do I make VS generate a new folder on the C: drive or desktop? / How do I use One click update?

Tags: c#, wpf

Thank you for taking the time to read my post.

1.) How would I make Visual Studio (WPF Project) generate a folder on the C: drive? ( I want to make a button so my users can generate a folder to put their shortcuts in so the program can launch them.)

2.) I am confused about the One click updates in visual studio. I've looked it up for hours and played with it, but I can not seem to get it to work. My FTP will be Dropbox, since my application is going to be basic and doesn't need to be too professional.

Thank you for all future replies. I will respond when I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
string path = @"C:\New Folder";
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path))
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
```